# How to not always send header in angular to external server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

in my app.config i am sending

in header

```
app.run(function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['MyCode'] = 'buTTon5';
});
```

Above works great for all my internal web api calls,  but I do have some external api calls in which I cannot send them the header ,  how can I not send it,

**Error**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://us-zipcode.api.smartystreets.com/lookup?zipcode=10001&auth-id=350910987643333. Request header field MyCode is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To explicitly remove a header automatically added via `$httpProvider.defaults.headers` on a per request basis, Use the headers property, setting the desired header to `undefined`. For example:
>
> ```
> var req = {
>     method: 'POST',
>     url: 'http://example.com',
>     headers: {
>        'Content-Type': undefined
>     },
>     data: { test: 'test' }
> }
>
> $http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
> ```
>
> [--AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Yes,  this is better

Comment: -  I have a much more challenging one ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566750/angular-calling-google-maps-without-sending-header-need-to-omit

Answer (score 0):

To delete you need to use `interceptors`. you will receive config object of $http call.  check this updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/StsoCL5gshz04ZJpZmx5?p=preview)

interceptors:

```
app.config([
  '$httpProvider',
  function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push( function() {
      return {
        'request': function(config) {
          if (config.url.indexOf('smartystreets.com') != -1)
            delete config.headers.MyCode; //able to delete with interceptor request method
          return config;
        }
      };
    });
  }
]);
```

Comment: I ran across a stackoverflow answers that said that `transformRequest` are no longer aloud after 1.4.x  , strange that ur using 1.5

Comment: **Note:** Due to [5da1256](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5da1256fc2812d5b28fb0af0de81256054856369), `transformRequest` functions can no longer modify request *headers.*  If one needs to dynamically add / remove headers it should be done in a header function. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating from v1.3 to v1.4 - Server requests http](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#server-requests-http-)